# PHP - How To Compare Alike Data?

Tags: php

In PHP, how to compare two "alike" data? For instance, in this code:

```
$a = "cats are cool";
$b = "1. catS are cool!!!"

if($a == $b) {
    echo "TRUE";
}
else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

now the obvious output will be "FALSE". But to what I'm trying to achieve, as long as the keyword "cats are cool" is in `$b`, the result should be "TRUE". How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an exact match, use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

```
//Note the use of !== here, it's because stripos may return 0,
//Which would be interpreted as false without strict comparison.
if (stripos($string, "cats are cool") !== false) {

    //Cats are cool indeed.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your own logic, period. Either you look for keywords [e.g. you search how many occurrences of your whitelist pop up in your strings], or you compute some string distance metric, like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 0):

If you should find just first string in second you can use `strpos`

Answer (score 0):

use `stripos()`

```
if(stripos($b,$a) !== FALSE)
echo "found";
else
echo "not found";
```

Comment: @madara uchhiha you also written same answer. once check your answer..and may I knw why you downvoted my answer

Comment: My implementation is very different from yours. You are comparing the two strings, I am comparing a string to a known keyphrase. Which is what the question asked. It's true that `stripos` is a good solution, but you need to use it correctly.